# d3: unable to send mouse events to another svg element (event.target.__data__ is null)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, events, mouseevent

I'm trying to add a brush to a d3 line-chart I wrote, which already supported hovering through a `rect` to which i've attached `mousemove`. However, in order to avoid breaking the hover functionality, I need to initialize the d3 brush behind this `rect`, so that it's not capturing all the mouse events.

For the brush to work, I therefore need to send mouse events from the hover `rect` to the svg element behind it, on which I've initialized the brush, exactly like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/7612013), which captures the events from elements in front of the brush:

```js
.on('mousedown', function(){
  brush_elm = svg.select(".brush").node();
  new_click_event = new Event('mousedown');
  new_click_event.pageX = d3.event.pageX;
  new_click_event.clientX = d3.event.clientX;
  new_click_event.pageY = d3.event.pageY;
  new_click_event.clientY = d3.event.clientY;
  brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);
});
```

However, using the example, which is from 2013 and uses d3 v3, `brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);` throws an exception:

[image]

It appears that d3's `brush.js` is looking for an `event.target.__data__.type`, which doesn't exist because it's not a "real" event.

How can I avoid this? Is it no longer possible to "fake" d3 mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

I found this newer example, which actually seems to work: https://bl.ocks.org/mthh/99dc420cd7e276ecafe4ef4bf12c6927

It replaces the problematic code I mentioned with the following:

```js
const brush_elm = vis.select('.brush > .overlay').node();
const new_click_event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
    pageX: d3.event.pageX,
    pageY: d3.event.pageY,
    clientX: d3.event.clientX,
    clientY: d3.event.clientY,
    layerX: d3.event.layerX,
    layerY: d3.event.layerY,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window });
brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);
```